# 12.10 LAB: Arrays: Output values below an amount (help needed)

Tags: google-coral

Hi I really need help with this coral lab i dont understand what to do for the "Then, read another value from the input, and output all integers less than or equal to that last value." here's the prompt:

Write a program that first reads a list of 5 integers from input. Then, read another value from the input, and output all integers less than or equal to that last value.

Ex: If the input is:

50 60 140 200 75 100
the output is:

50 60 75
For coding simplicity, follow every output value by a space, including the last one. Then, output a newline.

Such functionality is common on sites like Amazon, where a user can filter results.

heres what i tried:

```
integer array(5) n
integer i
integer x

for i = 0; i < n.size; i = i + 1
   n[i] = Get next input
for i = 0; i < n.size; i = i + 1
   n[x] = Get next input

for i = 0; i< n.size; i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
integer array(5) n
integer i
integer x
for i = 0; i < n.size; i = i + 1
  n[i] = Get next input

x= Get next input

for i = 0; i < n.size; i = i + 1
  if x >= n[i]
     Put n[i] to output
     Put " " to output
Put "\n" to output
```

I hope this helps. I sometimes just need an example to get started.